# turtlebot + gazebo + simulated kinect

Tags: gazebo, kinect, rviz, turtlebot, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm having problem with reading simulated Kinect raw or rgb image. I'm running electric with turtlebot_gazebo on Ubuntu 10.04. I don't get any of the data to build point cloud in rviz. It is like that Kinect is not publishing to any of the topics even though I see /cloud_throttled [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] topic.

The only thing I can read (I assume from kinect?) and visualize in rviz is topic /scan [sensor_msgs/LaserScan].

Oh, and one quick question. Should turtlebots dashboard work in simulatated environment? Because if I call `rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard` the dashboard does come up, but only the middle icon under diagnostic is green.

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28410/turtlebot-+-gazebo-+-simulated-kinect/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-02-26**:
Nobody had this problems? Any tips?

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-03-14**:
the dashboard is only meant to work with the physical robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in the gazebo.urdf.xacro file. The camera frame names were not correct and therefore the gazebo plugins couldn't initialize properly. It's fixed in 330:4253a4e5f257 . It's released in turtlebot 0.9.2

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1